# WMS in leaflet R

Tags: r, leaflet, wms

I'm am trying to add a WMS-map with `leaflet`, however, I can't get it to work. Is it because the WMS-service has to be tiled or is there another reason?

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>%
  setView(lng = 12.526906, lat = 55.680339, zoom = 17) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addWMSTiles(
    "https://gis.frb-forsyning.dk/Varme/service.svc/get?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS",
    layers = "Ledninger",
    options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = FALSE)
  )
```

The WMS is unfortunately password protected, but you can find a XML-transcript of the WMS [here](https://frbforsyning-my.sharepoint.com/personal/todi_frb-forsyning_dk/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=09e0e60e805274e0f974ade862ec51733&authkey=AQb03UngdyFCuDe7ndIAKJw).

Comment: The XML declaration at the top of your GetCapabilites response appears to have some errors (even if you ignore that you can't connect to the service because of the password.  `http://gis.frb-forsyning.dk:443/varme/schemas/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd` should probably be **https** , you are missing namespace declarations for xsi and xlink

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to test your exact code, because the WMS service requires a password. I have tested it with a different WMS service and you probably have to remove the `?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS` part from the url, because you don't need the GetCapabilities request for the tiles. It needs the GetMap request, but that is added by the Leaflet Library.

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% setView(lng = 12.526906, lat = 55.680339, zoom = 17) %>% addTiles() %>%
addWMSTiles(
"https://gis.frb-forsyning.dk/Afloeb/service.svc/get",
layers = "Ledninger",
options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = F)
)
```

The code I tested and that worked is:

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet() %>% setView(lng = 5.3, lat = 50.9, zoom = 17) %>% addTiles() %>%
addWMSTiles(
"https://geoservices.informatievlaanderen.be/raadpleegdiensten/GRB-basiskaart-grijs/wms",
layers = "GRB_BSK_GRIJS",
options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = F)
)
```

Comment: Apologies, just realize that it is password protected. Will try to find a different WMS or remove the password. Stay tuned :)
Have already tried removing the ?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS, with no luck. The other WMS-service you posted works fine.

Comment: I have included a XML-transcript of the WMS, but I know that the code is still not reproducible.

Comment: Your GetCapabilities XML doesn't give much extra clues to what could be the problem, because both layer name and format seem to be correct. Do you run into similar problems with any other services that are publicly available? Does your browser console give any clues on any files that can't be loaded or other errors?

Comment: I haven't had problems with the few publicly available WMS's I have tried. The coordinate system should be okay as well. And I don't get any errors messages in the console.

Comment: What do you get when go to the url: https://gis.frb-forsyning.dk/Varme/service.svc/get?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&VERSION=1.1.1&LAYERS=Ledninger&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=false&HEIGHT=256&WIDTH=256&SRS=EPSG%3A3857&BBOX=1393599.8996953333,7494497.749304961,1393905.647808474,7494803.497418102

Does it give a valid tile?

Comment: Just gets a white square.

Comment: So probably it's a valid tile, and I think nothing is wrong with your R code, if you leave out the `?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS` part. Does your WMS service work in GIS software like QGIS or SAGA if you use projection EPSG:3857 at the same zoom level as your Leaflet code?

Comment: Yes, it's working in Geomedia.

Comment: Have you tried to add your username and password to the url? Maybe the password protection is the problem. You can try to change the url to https://`yourusername`:`yourpassword`@gis.frb-forsyning.dk/Afloeb/service.svc/get.

Comment: Actually I was wrong. I doesn't work in Geomedia in EPSG:3857 - only in EPSG:25832. This means that there must be something wrong with the WMS. I guess I must then try to use proj4leaflet to get over in EPSG:25832 - this may be a separate question...

Comment: Possibly the issue is limited scale in grouped layers